# Fourier coefficients of Bernoulli periodic polynomials in terms of sine and cosine.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, bernoulli-polynomials

I want to express the Fourier Coefficients of the Bernoulli Polynomials in terms of sine or cosine, where

$$B_n: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
with $S^1$ identified to $[0,1)$ (hence polynomials of period 1).

So far, I have that, if $n$ is odd, then

$$B_n(x) =  \frac{-i(-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}n!}{(2\pi)^n} \sum_{m \neq 0} \frac{e^{2i\pi mx}}{m^n}$$

and if $n$ is even, then

$$B_n(x) =  \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}+1}n!}{(2\pi)^n} \sum_{m \neq 0} \frac{e^{2i\pi mx}}{m^n}$$

However, I have also that $B_n(x)$ is even on if $n$ is even and odd otherwise.

Is there a way to derive the sine\cosine Fourier coefficients from those expressions?

I know that it's suppose to be
$$B_n(x) =  \frac{2(-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}n!}{(2\pi)^n} \sum_{m =1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2 \pi m x)}{m^n}$$

if n is odd, and

$$B_n(x) =  \frac{2(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}+1}n!}{(2\pi)^n} \sum_{m =1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2 \pi m x)}{m^n}$$

if n is even, but I can't find a way to prove it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the index of summation should be $m$. Anyways, in the sums of the RHS, change $m$ to $-m$ and see what you get.